# Validate radio button selected in each group

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

Here is the code. The "surveys" are generated elsewhere. I need validation that a radio button is clicked in each group of answers. The number of answers and answer groups will be variable.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- display a table of surveys -->
        <h2><?php echo $survey['title']; ?></h2>
        <form class="survey" name="take_survey" action="./take_survey" method="post">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <input type="hidden" name="survey" value="<?php echo $survey['id'] ?>" />
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Response</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($questions as $question) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $question['question']; ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php foreach ($answers as $answer) : ?>
                            <?php if ($answer['question_id'] == $question['id']) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $answer['answer']; ?></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="question_<?php echo $question['id']?>" value="<?php echo $answer['id'] ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="eventButtons">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Clear"  class="btn">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use radio buttons, it is non-conformant to the HTML spec to have a period when none are checked, so the browser might select the first one, but I think enough people use it that browsers won't enforce. When this posts to ./take_survey, you should check on that destination page what the form's post data includes a selection for each question. $_POST['5'] would be return the answer selection if the question I was 5. You should also use JavaScript to intercept the submit button and validate this on the browser before submitting. If you leave out the server check, you allow vulnerabilities

Comment: Good deal, thanks for the input!